# Nav Items with "bind" not showing after Navigating to Route

Tags: aurelia

I am facing a problem with my aurelia application not displaying specific Navigation Items that bind to whether a user is logged in or not. It;s driving me crazy and I hope someone here can help.

I have an *app.js* and *app.html* which has the login code (using Auth0). Please see below and I have tried commenting thoroughly where possible.

**app.js**

```
// I've imported a couple of stuff here for the code below to work
export class App {
    lock = new Auth0Lock('XXXXXXXX');
    isAuthenticated = false;

    constructor(http, router) {
        this.http = http;
        this.router = router;

        this.router.configure(config => {
            config.title = 'Sample App';
            config.map([
                {
                    route: ['', 'welcome'],
                    name: 'welcome',
                    moduleId: 'welcome',
                    nav: true,
                    title: 'Welcome',
                    settings: {
                        icon: 'fa-home'
                    }
                },
                {
                    route: ['form'],
                    name: 'form',
                    moduleId: 'form',
                    nav: false,
                    title: 'Provide your Details',
                    settings: {
                        icon: 'fa-user'
                    }
                }
            ]);
            config.mapUnknownRoutes({redirect: '#/'});
        });

        http.configure(config => {
            config
                .useStandardConfiguration()
        });

        this.isAuthenticated = tokenIsExpired() ? false : true; // checks whether the token from Auth0 is expired or still valid
    };

    login() {
        // If the user is successful, the code below gets executed
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        this.router.navigate('form'); // When the user logs in, they go to the page "form"
    }

    logout() {
        // Logout Code
    }
}
```

**navbar.js**

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {tokenIsExpired} from 'tokenUtils'; // tokenUtils is a js which checks for expired tokens

@inject(Router)

export class NavBar {
    @bindable router = null
    isAuthenticated = false;

    constructor(router) {
        this.isAuthenticated = tokenIsExpired() ? false : true;
    }
}
```

**navbar.html**

```html
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#skeleton-navigation-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <!--<i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                    <span>${router.title}</span>-->
                    <img src="img/header-logo.png" height="60">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                // Navbar left works well

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li if.bind="isAuthenticated">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="${profilePicture}" class="nav-profile-picture img-circle">
                            Hello, <span class="user-nav-name">${userName}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li if.bind="isAuthenticated">
                        <a href="#" click.trigger="logout()">
                            <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="loader" if.bind="router.isNavigating">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-2x"></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>
```

As seen from the code above, when someone clicks login from the *app.html* file, they go through Auth0 validation and when they are successful, they are redirected to the Form page. However, on the once the user gets redirected they are not able to see the links which have bind with isAuthenticated. The links only appear if I reload the page.

I do not know what I am doing wrong and I would appreciate guidance in getting this to work. Thank you for your time!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the navBar's function `tokenIsExpired()` is being called only once. So, navBar's `isAuthenticated` is not being updated. That's why the DOM is not updating.

To solve this, create another bindable property to tell your navbar whether the user is logged in or not. For instance:

```
export class NavBar {
    @bindable router;
    @bindable isAuthenticated;

    //remove the old constructor
}
```

Now, in your App html, bind `isAuthenticated` to the `NavBar`:

```
<nav-bar router.bind="router" is-authenticated.bind="isAuthenticated"></nav-bar>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh Wow! thanks!!! This got me on the right track to have it solved!! Great! I appreciate it!